# iphone menu like tap tap

Tags: iphone, menu

hi guys how do I make a menu like the one that tap tap "where to" app uses, (circular menu, that gets highlited when touched)

[image]

As I saw in some wwdc video they explain the design behind this app, they explain that the menu  was a table that goes to a view before being placed in the circle, so it haves a nav bar after an item has been chosen,

I saw this link [designing convertbot](http://tapbots.com/blog/design/designing-convertbot), they explain the design for their menu but not the coding or how it works (noob here!)

ok thanks a lot!

Comment: any luck finding an answer to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something kind of similar

[tapsandswipes](http://www.tapsandswipes.com/frameworks/touchpie/)

using core animation.

Would be possible to roll own menu